# How to save an empty array as property of a nested object in mongoose?

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongoose

I have the following code:

```
var lesson = new Lesson({
                classroomId: req.params.classroomId,
                name: req.body.name,
                startDate: startDate1,
                endDate: endDate1,
                teacher: {
                    _id: classroom.teacher._id,
                    attendance: [],
                },
                students: [],
            });

lesson.save();
```

When I check in the backend, the teacher key just has the _id property and the attendance property wasnt saved. I suspect this is because it is an empty array. How can I save an empty array like this?

Comment: try with assigning var att = [] and use this variable in attendance property like attendance: att;

Comment: I suspect it's actually because the defined schema does not match what you are submitting. Show your schema in the question if you are still unsure. Mongoose will create empty arrays in the document by default, even if you do not supply any data at all. The usual request is to "supress" that.  If you get no array, then your schema is not actually what you think it is.

Comment: This is the relevant part of the schema.
    teacher: {
        _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        attendance: [{
            connectTime: Date,
            disconnectTime: Date,
            _id: false,
        }],
    },

Answer (score 0):

It may be because Lesson Schema is not defined properly. Did you try setting...

```
mongoose.Schema({
    .....
    teacher: {
        ...
        attendance: { type: Array, default: [] }
    }
    ...
});
```

Comment: Ofcourse. That is just the part of the schema that is relevant.